# AWS Machine Learning Boto3 Splitting Data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, boto, boto3

When using boto3 to create a AWS machine learning model, is there an easy way to split your data-source when training the model (e.g. 70% to train source, 30% to evaluate it). I know that this is easy to do on the website's interface, and I figured it would be similar in boto3. However, from what I can tell it uses my entire data-source to train the model, so I'm left with nothing to evaluate it. Do I just have to split my data-source manually into two separate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [data rearrangement](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/data-rearrangement.html).

This document describes using the first 70% to create the data source:

```
{
    "splitting": {
        "percentBegin": 0,
        "percentEnd": 70,
        "complement": false,
        "strategy": "sequential"
    }
}
```

[This repo](https://github.com/awslabs/machine-learning-samples/blob/master/targeted-marketing-python/build_model.py#L44) also shows how to split using boto3 into train and test.

Comment: So when I call create_evaluation() and use the same data-source id will it automatically start at 70% and go to 100%?

Comment: Never mind seems that it doesn't. Thanks for the quick response though, works perfectly!